# Subscriber python CameraInfo and Image

Tags: ros, python2.7, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello i am new to ros and python. Need little help in how to subscribe to CameraInfo and Image of format sensor_msgs.msg and use its data for further image processing. Here are few lines of code that i am starting with:

```
from sensor_msgs.msg import CameraInfo, Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
import cv2

if __name__ == '__main__':
   rospy.init_node('node_name')
   while ~rospy.is_shutdown():
   sub_cam_info = rospy.Subscriber('/camera/rgb/raw_camera_info', CameraInfo)
   sub_rgb = rospy.Subscriber('/camera/rgb/raw_image_color', Image)
```

From here i want to extract header and data information from 'sub_cam_info' and 'sub_rgb'. Something like this:

```
camera_info_K = sub_cam_info.K
camera_info_dist_model = sub_cam_info.distortion_model
rgb_image = CvBridge().imgmsg_to_cv2(sub_rgb, encoding="rgb8")
```

And then use this data for image undistortion:-

```
rgb_undist = cv2.undistort(rgb_img.data, camera_info_K, camera_info_dist_model)
```

Mainly i need help in second part i.e. extraction of parameters from CameraInfo and Image msgs. However if someone can help me to sort out body of this whole code! I am already through making up my own CameraInfo and rgb messages, using them for undistortion and publishing on ROS by but now i want to get them from another ROS module and work with them.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321501/subscriber-python-camerainfo-and-image/) by [usamamaq](https://answers.ros.org/users/40953/usamamaq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2019-04-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok as many people has viewed this so i thought of answering my own question. I solved it like this.

```
import message_filters
import cv2
import rospy
from cv_bridge import CvBridge

def callback(rgb_msg, camera_info):
   rgb_image = CvBridge().imgmsg_to_cv2(rgb_msg, desired_encoding="rgb8")
   camera_info_K = np.array(camera_info.K).reshape([3, 3])
   camera_info_D = np.array(camera_info.D)
   rgb_undist = cv2.undistort(rgb_image, camera_info_K, camera_info_D)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   rospy.init_node('my_node', anonymous=True)
   image_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/ardrone/front/image_raw', Image)
   info_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/ardrone/front/camera_info', CameraInfo)
   ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([image_sub, info_sub], 10, 0.2)
   ts.registerCallback(callback)
   rospy.spin()
```

So my problem was how to subscribe on two different topics and use their data for further processing. "message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer" synchronized the incoming messages according to the time stamp with each message being received and with "ts.registerCallback(callback)" i was able to use both subscribed messages together for further processing in callback function.

---

Originally posted by [usamamaq](https://answers.ros.org/users/40953/usamamaq/) with karma: 146 on 2019-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-08-09**:
if this solved your issue you can accept your answer as correct by clicking the tick mark

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2021-04-28**:
If the camera driver is written properly, the image and its camera info should have the exactly same timestamps, so you should use ExactTime policy instead of ApproximateTime.